# Using "string" header file gives error in c++ on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, msvcrt

So I recently upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I didn't faced this type of error before but when I program in c++ and include "string" header file then it pops out an error when executing though compiling does not give any error. I tried using "cstring" and update Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable but no change. If I don't use "string" header file then it will not produce any error.

Here is test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string text = "Hello World!";
   cout << text;
   return 0;
}
```

On compiling it does not give error

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

But when I tried to execute via console it doesn't print anything.
And when I tried to execute by double clicking "test.exe" then it showed me this

[image]

Comment: As you are not using MSVC updateing the Redistributable package will have no effect.

Comment: Which version of GCC did you use and what type was it (MinGW, cygwin)?

Comment: Probably a screwed or incomplete gcc installation. Are those DLLs reachable by your `PATH` variable?

Comment: MinGW version is 6.3.0-1

Comment: Yes I Already added mingw path to system

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found what causes this error.
There was a faulty app which is set in my system path variable containing a faulty libstdc++-6.dll which causes this error. I remove the path from th system path variable and now everything working fine.